# Array in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance

when i use arrays mysql query it's really slow. are there any tricks that makes this faster?

e.g:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM posts
   WHERE type IN ('1','2','5')
ORDER BY id ASC
```

takes much longer then other queries.

Comment: Indexes?  Only return the columns you actually need - not all of them.

Comment: do an explain and see whats going on

Comment: `WHERE type=1 OR type=2 OR type=5`. Do you have got an index on type?

Comment: @str: `IN` is logically equivalent; there's no benefit to using `OR`s

Comment: `IN` is a comparison operator function

Comment: Ok, problem solved, sorry my bad :P. it was not about query, i've found some bugs on my php codes, when i fixed them, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If `type` is `integer` type, then remove apostrophes:

```
WHERE type IN (1, 2, 5)
```

If not - change `type` type to `integer`

Answer (score 0):

There a number of things to speed up queries I'd consider looking up the following:

Normalizing.  Perhaps the structure of your tables isn't the most efficient?

Indexing.  This will improve query times if you KNOW what you want to search on.

Answer (score 0):

[`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) will tell you why your query is slow. Based on that you can make adjustments to your query or your table structure to solve the problem. In this case, use it like this:

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type IN (1,2,5) ORDER BY id ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to look two things
First,  **('1','2','5')** this is string not integer it should be **(1,2,5)**. 
Second, you can apply indexes on **type** field.